# new intent in AsyncTask onPostExecute error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I want to call intent in an `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute` but I am getting an error,

This my code,

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
   if(name.equals("success")){
      // tv.setText("berhasil");
      // Toast.makeText(mContext, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
       getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
   } else {
       pDialog.setMessage(name);
       pDialog.show();
   }
   pDialog.dismiss();
   super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

anybody can help me to resolve this problem?? thanks before

this error log

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: aws.sample.com.sampleawsconnection, PID: 9959
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatLollipop$OnApplyWindowInsetsListenerBridge;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatLollipop; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop' appears in /data/app/aws.sample.com.sampleawsconnection-2/base.apk)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LollipopViewCompatImpl.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:1646)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:2996)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:425)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at aws.sample.com.sampleawsconnection.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:15)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: replace this getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent); with startActivity(intent); and try. if this doesn't work try this.startActivity(intent);

Comment: i was try this, but still error force close, any idea??

Comment: try Nick Cardoso's Answer

Comment: can you please post error log?

Comment: Are you sure the setMessage line isnt the error? Where is pDialog initilaised?

Comment: but @NickCardoso that is the else part. We can't understand the problem before logcat error. I think the error is in his SecondActivity.class

Comment: According to me your error is in SecondActivity.class please check. and post your logcat error

Comment: hahahaha the error is in your secondActivity please debug and check first. @Bloom

Comment: You win this round Zaki

Comment: i was posting log chat error.... can you help me??

Comment: Show us the class implementation on onCreate method of secondActivity

Comment: post your secondActivity code

Comment: Also show us your gradle dependencies, is your app compat current?

Comment: i was posting in secondActivity...im confused why error :(

Comment: @Bloom please post full activity code and also post your app gradle file code

Comment: @ZakiPathan my problem in SecondActivity... after i change.. this program is running...thank you so much

Comment: Welcome @Bloom Happy to help you :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start an activity from an application context without `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Two options (1) Pass in your activity context to the task (bad, causes leaks) or (2) add the flag:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Edit: I've just noticed you have access to `MainActivity.this` which means you're an inner class so you can just do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Please ensure your gradle file is up to date (you might need to sync the newest build tools):

```
compileSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion to 25

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
```

Comment: i was try this, but still error force close, any idea??

Comment: check the gradle lines i have outlined

Answer (score 0):

update your older library to newer one.
Like

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

And also update `compileSdkVersion` to 24, `buildToolsVersion` to 24.0.1, `targetSdkVersion` to 24.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Pass context object in constructor of Asynctask and use that context to startActivity in postexecute